# Comparing data from two different time periods

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, time

I am trying to compare DWI frequency over the period of 3 years. I want to create 3 maps, with each one showing where DWI's occurred during 2011, 2012, and 2013. I have the point data for this, but I am unsure on the best way to display it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using either [Kernel Density (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000000s000000) or [Point Density (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000000v000000) to represent the magnitude per unit area in raster format.  Once you have the KDE, [Reclassify (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) the raster into useful classes.

**Kernel Density**

> Calculates a magnitude per unit area from point or polyline features
>   using a kernel function to fit a smoothly tapered surface to each
>   point or polyline.

[image]

**Point Density**

> Calculates a magnitude per unit area from point features that fall
>   within a neighborhood around each cell.

[image]

Comment: Great idea that would look great. I went to do it though and turns out the ArcMap I am using does not have the spatial analyst extension unfortunately. Kind of limits what I can do.

Comment: You can also accomplish this in the open-source QGIS using the heatmap plugin: http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html